# JS: Cannot read property of 'src' of Undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check all input boxes if there is an image tag next to it that contains a certain image location in it's `src`.

```
var productThumb = document.getElementsByTagName("img").src;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = inputs.length; i < max; i++) {
    imgSrc = productThumb[i];
    if (inputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && imgSrc.indexOf("/img/folder/1/") === 0 )
        inputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

When I run this code  I get the error in the title. What is wrong? I'm new to javascript so I have no idea what I am doing wrong but I think it has to be something with `var = productThumb` and `imgSrc = productThumb[i]`. What is the correct way of declaring the variables?

Comment: You have to put all the image references into an Array if you want to be able to access them by index position.

Comment: Your title is missing the name of the property it cannot read, which is probably quite important. Care to update?

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of [What does `getElementsByClassName` return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return).

Comment: @Robert Rossmann Sorry, I've updated the title.

Comment: If the error says the engine cannot read some property of `undefined`, it means, contrary to your expectations, that you are getting `undefined` where you would expect an object. I would go ahead and double-check the return value. In your example, it looks like this is the offending code: `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`.

Comment: Why do you think `getElementsByTagName("img")` would return something different than `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`. You are treating one as an array and one as a DOM element.

Comment: Btw, this code cannot produce the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like structure (an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)). Thus, `productThumb` is undefined because there's no `src` property in an `HTMLCollection`.

Simply remove `.src` from line 1 in your example, and add it at the end of line 4, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've tried this prior to posting this question. I get a similar error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined(…)

Comment: I can't replicate your exact problem without more code; as far as I can tell, the code works properly as per this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/a64umcbr/

Comment: I added alert and console log code to see if the code is actually  looping through the img tag and it appears to do it. It get's undefined after the last img for some reason. I will do some more debugging. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
var productThumb = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = inputs.length; i < max; i++) {
    imgSrc = productThumb[i].src;
    if (inputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && imgSrc.indexOf("/img/folder/1/") === 0 )
        inputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

This is because, in line 1, `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of img elements. And hence, getting src from an array of elements doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper solution would be to simply add  [0] in front of .src this will choose which img within the collection to reference.

Example.

```
var productThumb = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, jQuery provides a simple solution.

This

```
var productThumb = document.getElementsByTagName("img").src;
```

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

Would become this

```
$productThumb = $('#PARENTid').find('img')[0].src;
$inputs = $('#PARENTid').find('input')[0].src;
```

Now for additional compatibility, if multiple libraries in use( which they likely are )

```
jQuery(function($){                                                      
$productThumb = $('#PARENTid').find('img')[0].src;
$inputs = $('#PARENTid').find('input')[0].src;                                     
});
```